# Удалить каждый второй элемент из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Задача состоит в следующем:

Дан список строк. Нужно убрать из списка каждый второй элемент. Например:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4'] => ['2', '4']
['qwerty', 'asdfg', 'zxcvb'] => ['asdfg']
```

Я захотел написать однострочное решение данной задачи. Моя попытка:

```
return [i for i in spisok if spisok.index(i) % 2 == 0]
```

Код, естественно, не работает на списках, в которых присутствуют повторяющиеся значения, так как метод `list.index()` возвращает индекс *первого* вхождения в список. Конечно, легко решить задачу при помощи многострочного кода, вроде

```
i = 1
while index < len(spisok):
    del spisok[i]
    i += 1
return spisok
```

Но все-таки, существует ли однострочное решение данной задачи? Хотелось бы узнать

- Самое лаконичное решение
- Самое понятное решение
- Самое запутанное решение (☻)

Comment: `['1', '2', '3', '4'][1::2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
l=['1', '2', '3', '4']
def q2 (l):
    return l[1::2]

def qq2(l):
    return [l[i] for i in range(1,len(l),2) ]

def qqq2(l):
    return list(dict(filter(lambda pair: pair[0]%2 == 1, dict(zip(range(len(l)), l)).items())).values())

def r(l):
    return [] if not l else r(l[:-1]) + [l.pop()] if len(l) % 2 == 0 else r(l[:-1])

print(q2(l),qq2(l),qqq2(l),r(l))
```

---

Вывод

```
['2', '4'] ['2', '4'] ['2', '4'] ['2', '4']
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно удалить каждый второй элемент:

```
arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4']


del arr[::2]
```

Answer (score 3):

В копилку запутанных (и, заодно, неэффективных) решений :)

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
print(pd.Series(lst)[pd.Series(lst).index.to_series().mod(2).eq(1)].to_list())
```

```
['2', '4']
```

И еще одно, надеюсь, достаточно запутанное:

```
out = [x for x, even in zip(lst, list(reversed(range(2))) * (len(lst) // 2)) if not even]
```

Comment: Последнее понятное,  индексируем все 0,1 и выбираем что-то одно 0 или 1, только реверс не понятно зачем.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю в качестве варианта (хотя лучший вариант был дан в комментарии)

```py
from itertools import compress, cycle


a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
b = ['qwerty', 'asdfg', 'zxcvb']

print(
    list(compress(a, cycle((0, 1,))))
)
# ['2', '4']

print(
    list(compress(b, cycle((0, 1,))))
)
# ['asdfg']
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Даже не знал, что есть такие функции.

Comment: @Глеб, самый основной цимес этого способа это то, что можно выбрать элементы по "карте", к примеру, чтобы выбрать каждый первый четвертый и пятый нужно взять `cycle((1, 0, 0, 1, 1,))`

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```py
return [e for i, e in enumerate(spisok, 1) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Нерабочее решение, т.к. enumerate возвращает первым индекс, а вторым - значение, а у вас обрабатывается наоборот - возвращается список индексов для элементов, делящихся на 2 без остатка

Comment: @АлексейР да, понял теперь исправил.