# Перемножить цифры числа (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, умножение

Задача:

Дано целое число. Написать функцию, возвращающую произведение цифр числа.

Примеры:

```
multiply(1)     => 1
multiply(123)   => 6
multiply(1024)  => 0
multiply(1111)  => 1
```

Мое решение:

```
def multiply(n):
    c = 1
    for i in str(n):
        c *= int(i)
    return c
```

Хотелось бы узнать другие решения. А именно:

- В одну строку (не смог догадаться, как это делается)
- Интересные (с дандер-методами)
- Запутанные

Comment: Делить на 10 и перемножать остатки от деления до тех пор, пока число не станет нулём

Comment: ``from functools import reduce`` ``return reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)*int(y), str(n))``

Comment: @Глеб Это да...

Comment: Не понял того, кто проголосовал за закрытие по причине "Невозможно дать объективный ответ". Почему невозможно-то?

Comment: @Глеб я проголосовал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, пункт "Любой ответ правильный", а также "нет реальной проблемы".

Comment: @Эникейщик, чем [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537851/Удалить-каждый-второй-элемент-из-списка) мой вопрос лучше? Я по тому же шаблону писал.

Comment: @Эникейщик, реальная проблема — поиск однострочного решения. Любой ответ правильный — не понял. Любой правильный ответ действительно правильный.

Comment: from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
reduce(mul, map(int, str(123)))

Comment: @Глеб кроме того, тут ТРИ вопроса, а не один. Как вы будете определять правильность "запутанного" решения?

Comment: @Эникейщик, опять же, см ссылку на предыдущий аналогичный вопрос. Там таких проблем не возникало. "Запутанный" — это просто для привлечения внимания к вопросу.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а правильность буду определять по количеству голосов.

Comment: @Глеб тогда это уже [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)

Comment: Но три вопроса в одном это недопустимо даже для соревнования

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё, что смог придумать =):

```
def func_1(n):
    r = 1
    for i in str(n):
        r *= int(i)
    return r

def func_2(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    r = 1
    while n:
        r *= n%10
        n //= 10
    return r

def func_3(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    r = 1
    while n:
        n, m = divmod(n, 10)
        r *= m
    return r

def func_4(n):
    from functools import reduce
    return int(reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)*int(y), str(n)))

def func_5(n):
    return int(__import__('functools').reduce(lambda x, y: int(x)*int(y), str(n)))

def func_6(n):
    from functools import reduce
    from operator import mul
    return int(reduce(mul, map(int, str(n))))

def func_7(n):
    return int(__import__('functools').reduce(__import__('operator').mul, map(int, str(n))))

def func_8(n):
    r = 1
    return [r:=r*int(k) for k in str(n)][-1]

def func_9(n):
    return __import__('functools').reduce(int.__mul__, map(int, str(n)))

def func_10(n):
    class MyInt(int):
        def __imul__(self, other):
            self *= other
            return self
    return __import__('functools').reduce(MyInt.__imul__, map(int, str(n)))

def func_11(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return n%10 * func_11(n//10)
```

Тесты по времени для общего понимаю скорости работы (`n in range(10**6)`):

```
func_1 1.3012542724609375
func_2 0.906489372253418
func_3 0.8345210552215576
func_4 2.6315038204193115
func_5 1.8639326095581055
func_6 2.851418972015381
func_7 1.4561686515808105
func_8 1.5701119899749756
func_9 1.3802201747894287
func_10 9.350691556930542
func_11 0.872490406036377
```

Answer (score 7):

В категорию "запутанных однострочников"

```
num = 7896
[f := int(x) * (f := 1 if i == 0 else f) for i, x in enumerate(str(num))]
print(f)
```

```
3024
```

И, поскольку никто пока не написал про `math.prod()`, то напишу:

```
from math import prod

num = 7896
f = prod(map(int, str(num)))
print(f)
```

```
3024
```

Answer (score 3):

Ввод, вычисление и вывод в одном выражении без трюков в виде импортов и побочных эффектов:

```
print(
    (lambda f, n: f(f, n))(
        lambda f, n: n % 10 * f(f, n // 10) if n >= 10 else n,
        int(input())
    )
)
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 | python dp.py
> 1
>
> $ echo 123 | python dp.py
> 6
>
> $ echo 1024 | python dp.py
> 0
>
> $ echo 1111 | python dp.py
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Без `str`'а, и, следовательно, побыстрее:

```py
def multiply(n):
    if n >= 10:
        c = 1
        while n >= 10:
            c *= n % 10
            n //= 10
        return c
    else:
        return n

print(multiply(1))
print(multiply(123))
print(multiply(1024))
print(multiply(1111))
```

Вывод:

```
1
6
0
1
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, исправил.

Comment: Интересный факт: на длинных числах алгоритм с последовательным делением работает за *K^2*, где K - число разрядов в числе. А преобразование в строку (то есть преобразование системы счисления с основания 2 на 10) можно сделать за *KlogK*.